# Null Pointer error when apply the theme

Tags: android

I set in my manifest the theme android Holo.Light.NoActionBar, but i have this error:

```
    01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.com/com.com.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at felastech.websourcerequest.Home.onCreate(Home.java:51)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-13 21:52:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(25087):    ... 11 moreactivity ComponentInfo{com.com/com.com.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The code:

```
<activity
       android:name="com.com"
       android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If i remove:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Everything works..

Comment: Include full stacktrace, especially the "caused by" exception.

Comment: i edit the first post

Comment: NPE in Home.java row 51 - what's there?

Comment: Add Home.java to the post.

Comment: perfect i resolve! in line 53 there is a error

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept that answer. It ensures the question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve that in my Home.java i remove this:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```